# Disjoint set implementation in Python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, disjoint-sets

I am relatively new to Python. I am studying Disjoint sets, and implemented it as follows:

```
class DisjointSet:
    def __init__(self, vertices, parent):
        self.vertices = vertices
        self.parent = parent

    def find(self, item):
        if self.parent[item] == item:
            return item
        else:
            return self.find(self.parent[item])

    def union(self, set1, set2):
        self.parent[set1] = set2
```

Now in the driver code:

```
def main():
    vertices = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'h', 'i']
    parent = {}

    for v in vertices:
        parent[v] = v

    ds = DisjointSet(vertices, parent)
    print("Print all vertices in genesis: ")
    ds.union('b', 'd')

    ds.union('h', 'b')
    print(ds.find('h')) # prints d (OK)
    ds.union('h', 'i')
    print(ds.find('i')) # prints i (expecting d)

main()
```

So, at first I initialized all nodes as individual disjoint sets. Then unioned `bd` and `hb` which makes the set: `hbd` then `hi` is unioned, which should (as I assumed) give us the set: `ihbd`. I understand that due to setting the parent in this line of `union(set1, set2)`:

`self.parent[set1] = set2`

I am setting the parent of `h` as `i` and thus removing it from the set of `bd`. How can I achieve a set of `ihbd` where the order of the params in `union()` won't yield different results?

Comment: You shouldn't take the `parent` argument in the constructor, since the caller doesn't have any choice about what to specify.  You should populate it in __init__ instead of main()

Comment: Here's a Py impl: https://www.nayuki.io/res/disjoint-set-data-structure/disjointset.py. Another one: https://github.com/mrapacz/disjoint-set

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your program is not working correctly because you have misunderstood the algorithm for disjoint set implementation. Union is implemented by modifying the parent of the **root** node rather than the node provided as input. As you have already noticed, blindly modifying parents of any node you receive in input will just destroy previous unions.

Here's a correct implementation:

```
def union(self, set1, set2):
    root1 = self.find(set1)
    root2 = self.find(set2)
    self.parent[root1] = root2
```

I would also suggest reading [Disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) for more info as well as possible optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

To make your implementation faster, you may want to update the parent as you `find()`

```py
    def find(self, item):
        if self.parent[item] == item:
            return item
        else:
            res = self.find(self.parent[item])
            self.parent[item] = res
            return res
```